# GetContentHeight() does not work properly

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to retrieve the height of a webview's content. it contains a html-string.
The problem is that getContentHeight() returns always the same value (392), no matter how long the html-string is.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has driven me nuts. Let me make a guess: Your content isn't loaded from the web or from the file system instead you make a call to `WebView.loadData()` or `WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl()` (where you specify `null` or an empty string in the latter case). Right?

If yes, then I guess I have a solution for you which was inspired by [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4b0a0a25a42de4ce): Be sure to use the `WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl()` method and provide a `baseUrl` which is not `null`, not an empty string and is different for different content data. According to the SDK documentation the `baseUrl` is only used to evaluate relative URLs inside the data (e.g. `<img>` tags not specifying the domain name in their `src` attribute), so if your data does not reference external content I guess you can generate "virtual" URLs (haven't tried this).

It seems as if the `WebView` is taking a look at the URL and if it doesn't change all subsequent calls to `loadData...` will result in the same height of the `WebView`.

Comment: Yes, it is like that. I finally solved the problem by inserting an anchor into the text and instantly jumping to this anchor an loading (I needed the height to scroll an certain amount). But I was indeed puzzled that getcontentheight didn't work... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: giving a fake url does not seem to work. I am still getting content height as 0. @nob , any pointers on how to get an anchor solution working ???

Comment: So, in order to get around this, I'm generating a random URL every time.  Lovely.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with getContetHeight() as well. 
First in the [WebViewClient.OnPageFinish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) callback the content height wasn't already set so what I did it's pretty rought solution.

```
Handler h;
Runnable scroll_updater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Thread.interrupted())
            return;

        if(lyrics.getContentHeight() == 0)
            h.postDelayed(this, 100);

        setLyricsScroll();
    }
};
```