# WebView getContentHeight() result not valid

Tags: android, webview

I have create a custom webview which override onScrollChanged()

```
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int left, int top, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {
        int contentHeight = (int) Math.floor(this.getContentHeight() * this.getScale());
        int webViewHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();
        super.onScrollChanged(left, top, oldLeft, oldTop);
    }
```

and in my activity

```
 customWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                int contentHeight = (int) Math.floor(view.getContentHeight() * view.getScale());
                int webViewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        });
```

However, the result come out for contentHeight doesn't the same.

**For example,**

From `onScrollChanged` -> contentHeigth => 510, webviewHeight => 478

From `onPageFinished` -> contentHeight => 240, webviewHeight => 478

What happen here ? please advice.

**NOTE**

`getScale()` value is same in both methods.

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773645/getcontentheight-does-not-work-properly

Comment: I have try it. but I think it was different issues. I didn't get 0 but different value. also, I have try to change from loadData() to loadUrl() still same.

Comment: Shouldn't it be customWebview.getScale() ?